# GridFS to store files in MongoDB using Mongoose and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

I started out with little to NO knowledge on how to store a file to a NoSQL MongoDB using Mongoose and Angular. 
After lots of research I ended up with the answer to my problems, I would have to use GridFS. Problem is that I have found various methods on how to use GridFS but never have I ever found one explained in detail and I can only seem to find the Mongoose side for it.
I was wondering if someone could enlighten me on how to upload a file using Angular and Mongoose together

Answer (score 0):

There are primarily two ways to do that.

Firstly the Grid FS one which I would not recommend because then you'll be saving the whole chunk directly in the Database and the GRID FS system actually makes parts of the file to save it so that speed is not compromised heavily. But still the payload size will be affected.

Check this Tutorial http://excellencenodejsblog.com/gridfs-using-mongoose-nodejs/
Second Method - Which I have used

Use File System to save the file and then save it's URL in the Mongo DB.

Steps

Use ng-file-upload module for the angular part. It is very easy and has many ready to use demos available.

Use Module like Multer at the backend for node js to save the file in the file system and then you can directly call function which will finally save the data in database after file is saved in file system.

Multer and ng-file-upload, both are very famous and support community is very vast.

Please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: thanks I'm reading into ng-file-upload and created this fiddler to help understand my problems and help me out. https://jsfiddle.net/rdsqgxoj/16/
problems so far :
 Button won't disable when no file is chosen,
 The '*required' mark won't disappear when file in chosen,
 I want some sort of control that the file has the correct format before I upload it and some sort of alert that will tell you it's an incorrect file format.

Comment: Tom please go through ng-file-upload's documentation. Whatever you have mentioned is possible directly using its ready made features.

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/544/ for required related requirements of yours and to restrict the file types use : ngf-pattern="'.pdf,.jpg,video/*,!.jog'" I will again request you to check validations in the documentations mentioned there. Best of luck.

Comment: I got this part working now thanks a lot! But now I'm stuck at the Mongoose bit, I used multer and got a pretty good idea as to how I receive the file in the path but I still have no idea how to store the file into my MongoDB so I'm stuck at this bit `app.post('/Upload', upload.single('solution') ,function (req, res, next) { });` so now how do I upload it. Haven't found any basic tutorials or documentation on the github page

Comment: Multer wont save the image in your database. It will save the file in file system - as in directory of your system and you can have path of that file in your database. Please read the original answer for that. Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Oh yes i inderstand now, thank you so much! I opened a new thread that's built upon this information I gathered and I explained it more accurate please read this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34576507/storing-a-file-into-mongodb-using-multer-in-mongoose

Comment: I have answered your on that thread as well. Please try to understand the basic concept first brother. Please read my answer here first. You are confused between saving files in file disk system and directly to mongo database. And if answers fulfill your request please accept them as answer.

Comment: could you perhapd help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34607846/downloading-a-file-from-mongoose-in-angular/34610814?noredirect=1#comment56981001_34610814 ?