# Downloading a file from Mongoose in Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've managed to upload a file and store it in my MongoDB, but now I want to be able to downlaod this file from the same mongoDB. In server-side I'm using the GridFS module in Mongoose to upload and download using the gfs-read/write-stream.
Downlaod code in Mongoose looks like :

```
app.post('/Download', function (req, res) {
    grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
    var gfs = grid(conn.db);
    var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
        filename: 'Program.cs'
    });
    readstream.pipe(res);
})
```

In my angular i have this so far:

```
$scope.Download = function () {
        $http.post(url + "/Download")
        .success(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        })       
 }
```

the console.log response is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFM5j.png)

I want to save this content into a .cs file in my local file system, also want to be able to prompt the user for the download-path, How do I do this?

Comment: are you able to download the file locally ?

Comment: That's what I want to acomplish :) so.. not yet I'm just getting the file/file-content in my angular and don't know what to do with it to make it store in a file locally

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
app.post('/Download', function (req, res) {

    var filenameId = "";// mention _id value of 'Program.cs'

    var filename = 'Program.cs';

    var _id = new ObjectID(filenameId );

    var gfs = new Grid(conn.db, "yourfile_collection_name");// default value is fs 

    gfs.get(_id, function(err, data) {    
        if (err)
          throw err;
        res.setHeader('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="' + filename + '"');
        res.send(data);
      });
};
```

Comment: and What do I do in Angular then? How do I store the file locally?

Comment: No it returns "refferenceError: ObjectID is not defined"

Comment: use  gfs.get(filenameId  , function(err, data) {  

Make sure that filenameId has valid value

Comment: Now it returns : "ReferenceError: Grid is not defined"

Comment: make sure following import 

var Grid   = require('mongodb').Grid;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99910/discussion-between-ganesh-karamala-and-tom-kustermans).